# Is there a way to get this book in Helgen (without tcl)?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

[image: Unreachable book below the crosshair, under table in Helgen]

Below the crosshair. Links to high-res. album featuring three more glamour shots.

The room is the first one you enter if you pick Hadvar and at the end of the passage whence the two Imperials-that-you-have-to-fight come if you pick Ralof. The table intersects with the shelf. I'd also rather not fling-things-at-it-until-I-knock-it-close. I'm also trying not to use mods (including unofficial patches) until a certain point, so, while it'd be nice to know if the USkP fixes this, I'd like to know an alternative to it too.

Comment: Why would you not use the USKP?

Comment: Because I'm setting a start. If I later decide or need, for whatever reason, to remove all mods (e.g., I'd rather show someone the base game at first rather than with mods to show the effect mods have) (or a mod that I really like or want to try is incompatible with the USkP (unlikely I know)), I'll have a starting save that I shouldn't have to worry about compatibility for.

Answer (score 1):

It is patched by the [Unofficial Skyrim Patch](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/19/?) (A.K.A. USKP). It moves the table to the left (so that the table and the shelf don't intersect, at least not so much; enough that the book becomes accessible). [The change log](http://www.iguanadons.net/Unofficial%20Skyrim%20Patch%20Version%20History.html) isn't descriptive enough or too difficult to decipher for me that I don't expect not to miss it and thus bother to find where it is mentioned.

Comment: He's not looking forward to use the Unofficial Patch at he mentioned in the question.